# Using a single pattern to capture multiple values containing in a file in lua script

Tags: lua

i have a text file that contains data in the format YEAR, CITY, COUNTRY. data is written as one YEAR, CITY, COUNTRY per line. eg -:

- 1896, Athens, Greece
- 1900, Paris, France

Previously i was using the data hard coded like this

```
local data = {} 

data[1] = { year = 1896, city = "Athens", country = "Greece" }
data[2] = { year = 1900, city = "Paris", country = "France" }
data[3] = { year = 1904, city = "St Louis", country = "USA" }
data[4] = { year = 1908, city = "London", country = "UK" }
data[5] = { year = 1912, city = "Stockholm", country = "Sweden" }
data[6] = { year = 1920, city = "Antwerp", country = "Netherlands" }
```

Now i need to read the lines from the file and get the values in to the private knowledge base "local data = {} "

Cant figure out how to capture multiple values using a single pattern from the data in the file.

My code so far is

```
local path = system.pathForFile( "olympicData.txt", system.ResourceDirectory )
 
-- Open the file handle
local file, errorString = io.open( path, "r" )
 
if not file then
    -- Error occurred; output the cause
    print( "File error: " .. errorString )
else
    -- Read each line of the file
    for line in file:lines() do
        local i, value = line:match("%d")
        table.insert(data, i)
        
    -- Close the file
    io.close(file)
    
end
 
file = nil
```

Comment: your code is missing an end to close the for loop. you're just matching a single digit per line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you read a line like

```
1896, Athens, Greece
```

You can simply obtain the desired values using captures.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1

> **Captures:** A pattern can contain sub-patterns enclosed in parentheses; they describe captures. When a match succeeds, the
> substrings of the subject string that match captures are stored
> (captured) for future use. Captures are numbered according to their
> left parentheses. For instance, in the pattern "(a*(.)%w(%s*))", the
> part of the string matching "a*(.)%w(%s*)" is stored as the first
> capture (and therefore has number 1); the character matching "." is
> captured with number 2, and the part matching "%s*" has number 3.
>
> As a special case, the empty capture () captures the current string
> position (a number). For instance, if we apply the pattern "()aa()" on
> the string "flaaap", there will be two captures: 3 and 5.

```
local example = "1896, Athens, Greece"
local year, city, country = example:match("(%d+), (%w+), (%w+)")
print(year, city, country)
```

Comment: `for line in file:lines() do
local year, city, country = line:match("(%d+), (%w+), (%w+)")
table.insert(data, {year, city, country})
end`

I want to insert the results as a new array element. But in this way its not working.

Comment: @NimeshWanigasuriya what is "is not working" supposed to mean?

Comment: its not inserting the 3 variables to the array

Comment: your code does not define a table data. try to print the captures values. maybe your file has different formatting than my example. I just showed you how to use captures. the rest is up to you

Comment: That was useful. Thanks alot